# Removing alerts (push notification) from IOS notifications area

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I currently working on implementing push notification for an App using ***PushPlugin***.

My difficulty is, i am unable to clear the notification alerts when I an enter the App directly, instead of clicking the notification alert. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using iOS 7 device which doesnt delete the notification but iOS 8 automatically removes the notification.
So you have to customize the native code in the plugin.
First define the macro

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the PushPlugin, it's deprecated, use the phonegap-plugin-push instead (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/)

It has a method to set the badge number, if you set it to 0 it will delete the notifications

```
push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() {
    console.log('success');
}, function() {
    console.log('error');
}, 0);
```